# React-md Buttons display

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

Does anyone know how to create a button using react-md on react js? The purpose of the button is if you click on one of them it turns blue and the other is disabled and turned to grey color. Do you have any similar examples to it or could you point to tutorials regarding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:
1. Create an onClick event for your button:

```
handleClick(){
this.setState({isClick: true})
}
```

2. On render you can create an object for style:

`Const buttonStyle = this.state.isClick? style.active : style.disable;`

3. Create an object style for you button:

   `const style = {
   active: //css here,
   disable: //css here
   }`
4. Apply that buttonStyle to the component:

   `<Button style={buttonStyle}> </Button>`

Comment: how would you call handleClick or is it automatically called?

Comment: No, you add it to the button you want the handle that event mate.

Comment: Just add to this: <Button onClick= {this.handleClick} style={buttonStyle}> </Button>

Comment: would I create the object style in the same js file or in index.css and then link it?

Comment: For a small project, you can create your object in your same file js

Comment: Or even you can do inline Style: <Button style= {this.state.isClick?{color: "red"}:{ color: 'blue'} }> </Button>

Comment: How are you doing mate? Is there anything more I can help?

Comment: I keep on getting a destructuring state assignment error on the button. do u know what that means?

Comment: also, i have 2 buttons. One of them if I click it should blue and other is disabled and turned grey and vice versa.. is that what your codes does?

Comment: I just demonstrated for you this code. Check this link: https://codesandbox.io/s/zrr3ok4y3

Comment: You're an absolute legend. Thanks :)